# What GUI tools can be used for PostgreSQL in Mac OS X?

Tags: postgresql, mac-os-x

I have recently started using PostgreSQL with my rails app.

I was looking for a SQL GUI to the PostgreSQL database (for Mac).

Anything better than pgadmin3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the [wiki page](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools), many different tools available.

Comment: Any which you think is the best?

Comment: That's a matter of taste, I prefer pgAdmin.

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently developing a Mac client for PostgreSQL named [PG Commander](http://eggerapps.at/pgcommander/). My goal is to make the best designed PostgreSQL client for the Mac -- it's not as full featured as pgAdmin, but it's a lot easier to use.

Comment: Not having a Mac I can't really tell if your tool is superb (will ask my colleagues though) - but I am glad to hear about it.  Do you have any plans to port it to linux/Windows/VMS/etc.?

Comment: At the moment I have no plans to port it to other platforms. Unfortunately I just don't have the resources to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Check out **[JackDB](http://www.jackdb.com/)**, it's a database client entirely in your web browser.

There's no software to install locally so you can use it on Mac OS X, Linux, and Windows and it works on all major modern browsers (eg. Chrome, Firefox, IE, Safari, and Opera). It supports connecting to PostgreSQL, as well as MySQL, Oracle, and SQL Server databases.

*Full disclosure*: I'm the founder of JackDB.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experimenting DbSchema (www.dbschema.com). I've been using the trial version and I'm pretty close to purchasing a license. While there are lots of tools for editing and submitting SQL requests (I like DbVisualizer) I like features in DbSchema. First, it has an interesting graphical database schema design tool for creating schemas and then applying them to a database. Second, it has a graphical way of querying tables. The "graphical" part is selecting the join criteria, to use multiple tables. While I'm comfortable with SQL I'm also interested in a tool that will let others search tables without resorting to SQL.

I'm using it to manage a Postgres DB. Although I'm designing my schema from scratch DbSchema does "import" schemas from existing databases.

I should add that I'm using DbSchema in Mavericks with Postgres running on the same laptop. DbSchema doesn't act like a native app. It's probably a Java client app--which is not a problem for me.